Github SSO always prompts to "Sign In" (Cloud Enterprise)
Long time user, first time poster.

I have seen these other references to GitHub and Caching issues on Windows:

git push still asking for credentials even after caching credentials
Is there a way to cache https credentials for pushing commits?
How to fix Git for Windows keeps asking for Github credentials

None of those worked for me.  So here are my details to assist in finding the right solution to my problem.

Our company now uses GitHub. They have enforced SSO sign-ins. Plus they enforce using HTTP to Clone, Pull, Push, so we cannot use SSH.

I am on a Windows 10 workstation.
I have Git version 2.47.0.windows.2 installed.

Every-time I clone one of our repositories from the command line. I get 2 "Sign In" popups.
The GitHub Sign-In Dialog
Then, in the browser, I authenticate and Git resumes and I now have my code.
Later, if I use git pull it will ask me to "Sign In" again. It doesn't matter the amount of time between Clone and Pull.
Also, if I Push my changes, it will ask me to "Sign In" again.
I am expecting:
To have my credentials cached so I don't get prompted for each and every Push, Pull, Clone action I perform.
I have tried the following:

git config credential.helper store <-- no help
git config credential.helper manager <-- no help

Here is the results from git config --list --show-origin
file:C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
file:C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
file:C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
file:C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
file:C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig filter.lfs.required=true
file:C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig http.sslbackend=schannel
file:C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
file:C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig core.autocrlf=true
file:C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig core.fscache=true
file:C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig core.symlinks=false
file:C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig core.editor="C:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe" -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin
file:C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig pull.rebase=false
file:C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig credential.helper=manager
file:C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig credential.https://dev.azure.com.usehttppath=true
file:C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig init.defaultbranch=Development
file:H://.gitconfig     user.name=myname
file:H://.gitconfig     user.email=myemail@company.com
file:H://.gitconfig     credential.https://github.com.username=myusername
file:H://.gitconfig     http.sslverify=true
file:H://.gitconfig     http.sslbackend=schannel
file:H://.gitconfig     filter.lfs.required=true
file:H://.gitconfig     filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
file:H://.gitconfig     filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
file:H://.gitconfig     filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
file:H://.gitconfig     diff.tool=bc
file:H://.gitconfig     diff.tool.bc.path=c:/Program Files/Beyond Compare 4/bcomp.exe
file:H://.gitconfig     merge.tool=bc
file:H://.gitconfig     merge.tool.bc.path=c:/Program Files/Beyond Compare 5/bcomp.exe

What can I do to enable Caching of the credentials so I don't have to "Sign On" with every action I do. This has been an annoyance ever since we switched to GitHub.

Ther have been a number of changes to how GitHub handles tokens and multi-account sign-ins. I can't be sure this is the problem, but it's worth a try.

Uninstall old versions of the Git Credential manager - In the past the Git credential Manager was installed separately from Git. It's now baked into the git client on most platforms. Having an older version installed may interfere with normal got operations.
Update your git CLI -
Make sure you have a recent version of the Git cli installed. As of writing this answer, the current version is 2.47.0. As part of the installation make sure you install the latest Git Credential Manager.

Set the credential.username variable for your repository - The Git Credential Manager has been improved to better handle multi-account switching for Git. You can now set a special config value credential.username in local repository settings to enforce the use of a specific username. Your settings seem to suggest this has been set globally for your account as part of credential.https://github.com.username=myusername, but that = should be . as far as I can tell. You could also directly edit your config file to make sure it reads:
[credential "https://github.com"]
    username = <username>


Check your Credential Manager for Windows and delete an existing cached credential. Then sign in again.

An alternative you can try is to install the GitHub CLI. You can log into github using that as well and as part of the auth process, register it as your credential manager.
gh auth login --web --git-protocol https
gh auth setup-git


Thanks for the steps. Unfortunately, it didn't help. I am now suspecting our company might have configured us to force authentication every time.

You just saved me. Thanks!

@PrismElixir it's possible for your company to set a policy which prevents credential storage in the windows credentialmanager. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-stop-credential-manager-from-saving/61d95177-ee17-4d33-9560-250aa3dfad18

There are some config settings you can do to store the credentials in memory or on disk in that case. This doc walks you through the options.

https://github.com/git-ecosystem/git-credential-manager/blob/main/docs/credstores.md#dpapi-protected-files
